# Acer laptop screen broken external monitor suddenly not working

Tags: laptop, usb, display, hardware-rec, vga

I have an acer aspire laptop that has a broken screen, I have been using it for the last few months connected to an external monitor via VGA. I have never had any issue with this setup until the other day the VGA cable fell out of my laptop I put it back in as I normally would but it won't work. I have tested both the cable and monitor and they are fine I have tried "fn" + "f5" I can see my laptop adjust but not nothing happens on the external. The only time I get anything on the external is occasionally when I log in the monitor show the welcome windows page in poor quality but drops out before going to my desktop. This is leading me to believe that there is something wrong with either my video card VGA output, if this is the case can I get a USB to VGA adaptor? 
Thank you your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

While you could indeed get a USB to VGA adapter the chance that it will work without having to configure it is very small, due to this I think you won't be able to install it...

Instead you should contact acer or a computer repair shop to get it repaired.